# WordPress custom fields check box

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to make it so the last item doesn't show a comma. When I use 'rtrim' it puts the check boxes first and the element second. Here is what I have but it shows up before element on next line up.

```
<?php echo '<p>' . rtrim('Good with: ',',' . the_field('good_with')) . '</p>'; ?>
```

result:

Dogs, Cats
Good with:

Comment: could you be a bit more clear on what you try to achieve?

Comment: Put the whole thing you are trying to echo between double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_field` echo the string use `get_field`

```
<?php echo '<p>' . rtrim('Good with: ',',' . get_field('good_with')) . '</p>'; ?>
```

If you outside the loop then pass the post id

```
<?php echo '<p>' . rtrim('Good with: ',',' . get_field('good_with', $post_id)) . '</p>'; ?>
```

Comment: get_field returns empty values

Comment: It is inside the loop or outside the loop ?